# How to iterate over Visio Geometry rows

Tags: c#, visio

I am interested in finding the Geometry data (shown below) from a shape in Visio so that I can export it to something I can use in other projects.

[image: This is the data I want to export]

The thing is that I want to be able to draw things in Visio, export the Geometry data, and then reuse those images in different formats/applications.

By now I have managed to extract some data per shape from my Custom Ribbon, but I can't seem to get a hold of the data I actually want. Basically this is found by trial and error (and a good amount of intellisense).

```
        foreach (Visio.Shape shape in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePage.Shapes)
        {
            lstShapes.Items.Add(shape.Text + " (" + shape.Name + ") Type: " + shape.Type + " - Section: " + shape.get_Section(1) + " - GeoCount:" + shape.GeometryCount + " - LayerCount: " + shape.LayerCount);
        }
```

Right now I am looking into ways to find all selected shapes rather than all shapes in the document, unsure if that will help at all. I've been strolling through the various properties of the `Visio.Shape` but it does not seem like the Geometry data is there at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the selected shapes you can use the `Selection` property on `Window`.  Once you've got that you can loop through the shapes, sections and rows with something like this (note [I'm using LINQPad here](http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html), but the only difference is how you get hold of the application):

```
var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

var firstComponent = (short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionFirstComponent;

foreach (Visio.Shape shp in vApp.ActiveWindow.Selection)
{
    for (short s = firstComponent; s < firstComponent + shp.GeometryCount; s++)
    {
        var geoSection = shp.Section[s];
        for (short r = 1; r < geoSection.Count; r++)
        {
            var rt = shp.RowType[s, r];
            Enum.GetName(typeof(Visio.VisRowTags), rt).Dump();
            //You now have the shape, section and row and, if you want to,
            //you can get to cells by using CellsSRC syntax:
            //var someCellValue = shp.CellsSRC[s, r, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visX].ResultIU;
            //How you address the cell will depend on the row type that you're targeting.
        }   
    }
}
```

If you're using this for export then you might also want to look at saving the document as SVG.  Here are some options:

- [Page.Export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/page-export-method-visio)
- [HTML Export tool](http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/) from @Nikolay

One more alternative might be to look at the [Paths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/shape-paths-property-visio) / [PathsLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/visio-vba/articles/shape-pathslocal-property-visio)  properties of Shape.  For example, inside your foreach shape:

```
for (int x = 1; x <= shp.Paths.Count; x++)
{
    Visio.Path p = shp.PathsLocal[x] as Visio.Path;
    p.Points(0.1, out Array pntsArr);
    pntsArr.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Looking into this now, seems interesting. Trying this out in LINQPad as VS does not have a Dump() feature, so that will be left to future work.

Comment: I used System.Windows.Forms.Application, however it does not contain a definition for ActiveWindow. Did you use some other namespace for Application (in MyExtensions)?

Comment: Now I have a long list of strings saying visTagRelLineTo and visTagRelMoveTo. Getting somewhere, now just to extract those X/Y values. Nevermind that last comment, I had to change it to Visio.Application (in case someone else gets stuck)

Comment: Yes, sorry, Dump() can be replaced by wrapping in a Console.WriteLine or Debug.WriteLine instead - I'm just showing something readable so you can see the enum rather than an int/short.

Comment: You'll still need to check if you're dealing with a rel row type or a standard one and then act accordingly.  If it is a rel (relative to the size of trhe shape) type you'll have to calculate the value as a factor of the width or height of the shape, depending on whether you're in an X or a Y cell.  So you might want to get the Width and Height cells just inside your foreach shape loop.  If it's a non-rel row type then you can just get the cell result directly and this will be in local coordinates.

Comment: Yeah that was what I was thinking, I managed to get this over to a Visio Add In too now, by populating a ListBox. I also brought out the custom properties with the following snippet inside my foreach shape loop `shape.get_CellsSRC((short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionProp,(short)((short)VisRowIndices.visRowProp + 0), (short)VisCellIndices.visCustPropsValue).Formula;` (0 is the index) in case someone else needs to do this later. Now just to find height and width and I'm pretty much set. I also used your `shp.CellsSRC[s, r, (short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visX].ResultIU` to get the correct numbers.